# Android guessing number game? How to change random number when user gets it right?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the random number that is being generated when the app starts and ask the user for the new input? As you can see the current code shows that if the user guess the correct number, he will have to restart the app again. Instead of doing this, I want to keep on changing the random number whenever the customer gets it right.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int randomNumber;
int number;

public void randomNumberGenerator (View view){
    EditText userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userRandomText);
    do {
        number = Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText().toString());

        if (number == randomNumber) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your number " + number + "is equal to generated number. CONGRATULATION !! Try Again: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (number < randomNumber) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your number " + number + "is lower than generated random number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your number " + number + "is greater than generated random number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
          };
```

---

```
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_udemy);
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(20);
    System.out.print(randomNumber);
```

Comment: Then asks it again using while or some thing

Comment: When the user gets the number correct show him message that he guessed right and regenerate new random number and again ask for new input. This way every time user enters correct number he/she will get a new number to guess.

Answer (score 3):

Move these lines to `generateRandomNumber`

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(20);
System.out.print(randomNumber);
```

Then you could add this again when user guesses right

```
randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(20);
```

So your code would look like this

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(20);
System.out.print(randomNumber);
do {
    number = Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText().toString());
    if (number == randomNumber) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your number " + number + "is equal to generated number. CONGRATULATION !! Try Again: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(20);
    } else if (number < randomNumber) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your number " + number + "is lower than generated random number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your number " + number + "is greater than generated random number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```